# Django - Rest Framework foreignkey field to be a selectField in my react app

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I`m trying to create my serializers for my **React** app but I met some problems. I will give you an exemple

```
class City(models.Model):
 city_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Profile(models.Model):
 city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
.......more fields.......
```

Right now I thinking how to do the serializer. In GET request things are simple but on POST or PUT request I need **all data** from **City** model in my **React** app to select an option. I thing to do two serializers and in React to have two axios but I`m trying to find another solution. Can anyone faced with this problem to help me? 
Sorry for my english

Comment: You need all of the cities information returned when you query for a profile?

Comment: yes. I need all cities information when i edit my profile or when i create a new profile

Comment: I think you need to check `ModelSerlizer` with the nested property. Or One more way you can use `depth=2` in meta.

Comment: can you post your serializers?

Comment: i tried depth but is not helping me for my problem

Comment: in my rest framework api interface everything is working , but the problem is how to do it in React. How to bring all data from City Model

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a cities api, which returns all the cities. Then we can use that API to fetch list of city and show to user.

For that you can user `ModelSerializer` https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer

Comment: I was thinking about this option but I was looking for another option much easyer on react part. maybe this is the only option , to have two serializers.

Comment: What other type of options were you exploring ?